# How to generate Living Doc automatically each time after running tests via Test Explorer? Instead use command prompt every time after test run

Tags: visual-studio

How to generate Living Doc (html) automatically each time after running tests via Test Explorer? I do not want to run the command manually each time to generate the html report.

Tried using command prompt only but I want something programmatic, which generates the report after test run automatically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the AfterTestRun hook you can write code to programmatically call livingdoc.exe however [like mentioned in the bug here](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2701) it may or may not workout depending on your OS, specflow and test runner version.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = /*path to livingdoc.exe*/;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = /*arguments to livingdoc.exe*/;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Per my bug, I have found a workaround posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899896/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-order-for-nunit-onetimeteardown-test-hook-if-more-th

please let me know if you have any questions on it.


  [1]: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2701